# Get JSESSIONID in Angular applications

Tags: java, angular, jersey, httpresponse, jsessionid

hope you can help me with this.

I am developing an application using Angular 8, that calls some Java REST Services (not a Spring backend, the services are written using only Jersey). When developing backend services, i used Postman app to test them, and this took me to an error: it seems that Postman automatically manages JSESSIONID, so when i try to call my service in Angular application, i realised that i have to do it manually.

The real question is, how to manage that ID in Angular? When i call my first service, a login service, in "Network" session of Chrome console i can see in response's headers the field:

```
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=averylongstring
```

I tried, following different other questions, to get it with

```
response.headers.get('Set-Cookie')
```

but it returns null. If i write

```
console.log(response.headers)
```

in .subscribe method, i can't see any relevant header, picture is following:

[image]

How can I access to that id? Is an error in Angular response handling or in service? I tried to return first a custom serializable bean and then a javax.ws.rs.core.Response object, hoping to fix, but i get the same situation.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, *mostly while responding to authentication/authorization request,* the server uses "**Set-Cookie**" **to set an "Http-Only" cookie for JSESSIONID** to prevent XSS exploits, or so.

In these cases, **you cannot read/get JSESSIONID cookie from client side**, even if you see it on your browser's console.

Answer (score 0):

We use [ngx-cookie-service](https://github.com/stevermeister/ngx-cookie-service#readme) for managing cookies in our Angular applications. Here is how you can set it up:

```
npm install ngx-cookie-service --save
```

or

```
yarn add ngx-cookie-service
```

Add the cookie service to your `app.module.ts` as a provider:

```
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [ CookieService ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then, import and inject it into a constructor:

```
constructor( private cookieService: CookieService ) { 
  this.cookieValue = this.cookieService.get('JSESSIONID');
}
```

Alternatively you can just access `document.cookie` but that would be much less explicit.

Comment: trying. i want to ask you something: th presence or not of the jsessionid is dependent by my service? or is a tomcat (or maybe jersey, idk) feature? in other words, is my responsability to genereate the id server side and put it in my response?

Comment: and second, considering that i want to add my session id in every request, can i combine this module with something like an http interceptor easily? sorry for maybe stupid question, i am quite newbie :D

Comment: i tried your solution, but it didn't work. `this.cookieService.get('JSESSIONID');` returns an empty string, and if i put a console.log of service.getAll() i get an empty object: { }

Comment: you have to make sure that you check your cookies after the server set them for you. Without more details it's hard to say what's wrong.

Comment: i can see into the google chrome console, so i suppose it is present. this is chrome console's content, in session "Response headers":                                             Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Length: 1145
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Mon, 23 Mar 2020 11:01:17 GMT
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=527E3FD2528CB3839A920280F92A320D;

Comment: can you tell me which detail you need to know? i will explain everything